# react-native-video How to add timeout in component

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

code:

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';


<Video
  source={{uri: 'http://xxxxx.m3u8'}}
  // How to add  `timeout={6000}`
```

How to add timeout in component

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues?q=timeout